# Flatten List without using Flat() function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to flatten a given data without using flat() function. here is my implementation

```js
function flatten(ary) {
    var ret = [];
   
    console.log(JSON.parse(ary))
    for(var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
        if(Array.isArray(ary[i])) {
            ret = ret.concat(flatten(ary[i]));
        } else {
            ret.push(ary[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

console.log(flatten(["This is a string", 1, 2, [3], [4, [5, 6]], [[7]], 8, "[10, 11]"]));
```

```
expected output ["This is a string",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11]
```

it works without the string . But when I put the string inside the argument it doesnt works.I can not use flat() function that is the main problem. Thank you

Comment: why `parse`...?

Comment: What's the error you're getting? May you show the call that does work?

Comment: "doesnt works": what do you expect to happen. What is the expected output?

Comment: `JSON.parse` expects JSON as argument. You are not passing JSON as argument, but a JavaScript array. Did you mean `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: @trincot updated the question. JSON.parse for converting "[1,2,3]" to [1,2,3]

Comment: What do you expect from input  `[15, "15", "[15]", "[\"15\"]"]`

Comment: @evolutionxbox it shows "
Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 on line "

Comment: You will need a way to distinguish JSON strings from strings that do not contain valid JSON. There is no clean way to do this and any attempt will leave you vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: Why would you want to parse `"[10, 11]"` as JSON, and not `"This is a string"` ? -- they both are strings.

Comment: Remove your log statement.

Comment: may I know why you can't use the flat function tho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you see is because you are trying to interpret `This is a string` as JSON. What you should do, if you want to interpret JSON values, is to try-catch the `JSON.parse` that way the error will be silenced. Here's the modified code.

```js
function flatten(ary) {
    var ret = [];
   

    for(var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
        let value = ary[i];
        try{
           value = JSON.parse(value);
        }catch(e){}
        if(Array.isArray(value)) {
            ret = ret.concat(flatten(value));
        } else {
            ret.push(value);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

console.log(flatten(["This is a string", 1, 2, [3], [4, [5, 6]], [[7]], 8, "[10, 11]"]));
```

Comment: So what if I want to flatten `[[[" true "]]]` and want as result `[" true "]` and not `[true]`?

Comment: remove that json.parse thing if you do not want to convert strings into their json values

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten an array like this:

```js
function flatten(a) {
    while (a.some(Array.isArray))
        a = [].concat(...a)
    return a
}

a = ["This is a string", 1, 2, [3], [4, [5, 6]], [[7]], 8, "[10, 11]"]
console.log(flatten(a));
```

If there are possible json strings in the array you'd like to parse, do that beforehand, for example:

```js
function tryParse(x) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(x)
    } catch(e) {
        return x
    }
}

a = ["This is a string", 1, 2, [3], [4, [5, 6]], [[7]], 8, "[10, 11]"]

a = a.map(tryParse)
console.log(a)
```